# Create a new column based on the value under the existing cell

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column in a dataframe based on the value which is already in the next index of my dataframe. So the dataframe looks like this:

```
col1 col2
A   Test
A   Test1
A   Test2
B   BTest
B   BTest1
```

So it has to change for every new letter in this case, the final dataframe should look like this:

```
A  Test  Test1
A  Test1  Test2
A  Test2  
B  BTest  BTest1
B  BTest1
```

I want to plot this later in a directed graph, this is why i need to do this. Any idea to execute this without writing an exspensive for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and shift the column values up by 1 (so, `shift(-1)`):

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].shift(-1)                                                                                   

0     Test1
1     Test2
2       NaN
3    BTest1
4       NaN
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

---

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].shift(-1)
df

  col1    col2     new
0    A    Test   Test1
1    A   Test1   Test2
2    A   Test2     NaN
3    B   BTest  BTest1
4    B  BTest1     NaN
```

Comment: works in general, but afterwards I have to join it back to the dataframe over the index. the solution from krewsayder is the ocmplete solution

Comment: @PV8 Or just `df['new'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].shift(-1)` is there any issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want by doing a self join.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()

df = df.sort_values(['col1', 'col2']) 

df.reset_index() \
                .merge(df.shift(-1).reset_index(), \
                       how='left', \
                       left_on = ['index', 'col1'], \
                       right_on = ['index', 'col1'])\
               .drop('index', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Out[176]: 
  col1  col2_x  col2_y
0    A    Test   Test1
1    A   Test1   Test2
2    A   Test2     NaN
3    B   BTest  BTest1
4    B  BTest1     NaN
```

Comment: this is cool to join the complete dataframe, if you only need one column, the solution form @cs95 is the easier one